# How to get the parent activity context after moveTaskToBack()?

Tags: android

I have a Main Activity and Child Activity.

MainActivity will intent the ChildActivity and call moveTaskToBack(true) at last to hide itself, but not finish().

On ChildActivity, i want to access the getContext(),getApplicationContext() method from MainActivity, so how can i do that?

Thanks you.

Comment: already child Activity contains getApplicationContext() method as it is extending Activity.

Comment: @Gopal Rao, thanks you for comment. however, i have some reason i need to access the Context of MainActivity instead. Actually, the ChildActivity is a Dialog Service.

Comment: May be getParent() in ChildActivity will help you...

Comment: I try getParent(), but it return ViewParent Type. I also try cast the getParent() to MainActivity, but it occur (java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.xxxxx.MainActivity)

Comment: see here... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29

getParent() returns Activity

Answer (score 0):

One way you can access using static variable, like this

In parent class declare

```
    Public static String parentContext;
```

assign context in onCreate(...) method

```
    parentContext = parentActivity.this;
             or
    parentContext = getApplicationContext();
```

Now in your ChildActivity

```
    Context childContext = parentActivity.parentContext;
```

Comment: never maintain static references for Context(Activity). It leads to context leakage